# Redacting ASP.net web.config File Contents

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, security, web-config

Other than database connection strings, by default are there any sensitive values populated in web.config by Visual Studio 2008? What are `PublicKeyToken` values are these sensitive values? Would it be bad security practice to publish web.config files with connection strings redacted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PublicKeyToken` are not sensitive.

As to redacting connection strings, who are you afraid of? Who's going to get hold of your web.config?

Comment: This is for a project that goes to a public FTP server at school. The connection string is publicly known by other students, so it is not an issue. I was just curious if there was anything else that is populated in there by Visual Studio that was sensitive. I did not see any. Thanks for the fast response :)

Answer (score 1):

Public key tokens are used in association with private key tokens to sign .NET assemblies. The public key tokens are not sensitive. As for connection strings, it is common practice to encrypt the connection string and keep them in the web.config.